# getting contact name using phone number not working

Tags: android, android-contacts, telephony, contactscontract

I am using below code for getting incoming call number which works fine.

```
String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

In next step, I tried to get contatc name using method `getContactName(mContext,number)`:

```
    public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}
```

but the method always return `null` (my incoming call is one of my contacts and its number and `number` string are exactly the same. I don't know that why this code does not work. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the permission in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @chengsam. I have added it before. If we don't add this permission, app will be crashed because of security exception.

Comment: You may refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700475/getting-null-value-while-retrieving-the-contact-name-from-contact-email)